# Two pattern in one regular expressions

Tags: regex, clickhouse, re2

I am trying to combine a regular expression for two cases in a query to ClickHouse DataBase:

1. Up to symbol "@" =>  `(^[^@]+)`
2. Without domain 'company\' and 'company.com\' => `(?:company\.com\\\\\\\\+|company\\\\\\\\+)(.*)`

I have two ways that I found using the "regex online" :

1. `^company\\\\(.*)|^(.*)@|^(?!company\\\\.*).*$`
2. `(?<=company\\\\)(.*)|(.*)(?<=@)|^(?!company\\\\.*).*`

But, constructions `?!` and `?<=` are not supported (error : invalid perl operator).
I've used command `extract`, e.g. `extract(User, '(?<=company\\\\)(.*)|(.*)(?<=@)|^(?!company\\\\.*).*')`

Could you give me some advice to understand how to make this regex suitable way, please.

In brackets - should pass, out of - shouldn't:

1. company\[ABC-1D2E]
2. [ABC-DE]@company.com
3. [123-ABCDE]
4. [12345]

Comment: could you provide the examples that should pass and shouldn't?

Comment: sure) In brackets - should pass, out of brackets - shouldn't

1. company\\\[ABC-1D2E] 
2. [ABC-DE]@company.com
3. [123-ABCDE]
4. [12345]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like need to use the several serial calls of [replaceRegexpOne](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/functions/string_replace_functions/#replaceregexponehaystack-pattern-replacement):

```sql
SELECT str,
    replaceRegexpOne(str, '(.*company\\\\)(.*)', '\\2') preliminary_result_1,
    replaceRegexpOne(preliminary_result_1, '(.*)(@company.com)', '\\1') result
FROM (
    /* test data */
    SELECT arrayJoin([
        'company\\ABC-1D2E',
        'ABC-DE@company.com',
        '123-ABCDE',
        '12345'
        ]) str
)
/* result:
┌─str────────────────┬─preliminary_result_1─┬─result────┐
│ company\ABC-1D2E   │ ABC-1D2E             │ ABC-1D2E  │
│ ABC-DE@company.com │ ABC-DE@company.com   │ ABC-DE    │
│ 123-ABCDE          │ 123-ABCDE            │ 123-ABCDE │
│ 12345              │ 12345                │ 12345     │
└────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴───────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir! replaceRegexOne is good function, but the challenge is to use extract and make one complex regex for one field.